# Microsoft Graph: How to report phishing to tenant admin

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-addin, microsoft-graph-mail, office365-rest-client

I would like to use the Microsoft Graph to report suspicious emails on behalf of a user. Precisely, the reports should end up in the [User reported messages](https://security.microsoft.com/reportsubmission?viewid=user) view in Microsoft Defender.

I know I can create [Threat Assessment Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/threatassessment-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), but that sends the report directly to Microsoft, i.e. reports end up in the [Submitted for analysis](https://security.microsoft.com/reportsubmission?viewid=admin) view. I want to let the tenant admin decide whether to send to Microsoft or not.

In other words, I would like to implement the same feature as this button in Outlook:

[image]

How can I achieve this using the Microsoft Graph, or another Microsoft endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

Neither `v1.0` nor `beta` of Graph api doesn't support setting policy for threat assessment.

Those operations are only available via the corresponding [Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps) cmdlets

Resources:

[Security & Compliance Center PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/scc-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

[New malware filter policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-malwarefilterpolicy?view=exchange-ps)

[New anti-phish policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-antiphishpolicy?view=exchange-ps)

[New safe attachment policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-safeattachmentpolicy?view=exchange-ps)

[New safe link policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-safelinkspolicy?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Thank you for making clear that my request can't be achieved via MS Graph. I am still lost as to what command I should run to achieve my purpose though. I have looked into the `New-AntiPhishPolicy` page for example, but failed to see what parameter I should use. Precisely, I cannot find the text `submission` or `submit` in that page. Would you be able to suggest a specific command ? Thanks 

Comment: @ArnaudP I also cannot find any relevant powershell command. There is also New-AntiPhisRule but without any reference to 'submission' or 'submit'. Still you can ask new question.